# Sort 3D matrix depending on specific column

Tags: matlab

I have `3D` matrix `(10*10*4)` and I am trying to short each slice depending on the `2` column after that and depending on column `2` I want to delete all rows that have a value on column `2` less than `1` and greater than `17`.

I used this code to sort but it is not working

```
clc;
clear;
A = rand(10,10,4)
column = 2;
[values,indices] = sort(A(:,column,:)) 
B = A(indices,:,:)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for sorting.

```
clc;
clear all;
A = rand(10,10,4);
column = 2;
z=A(:,column,:);
[values,indices] = sort(z,1) ;
B=zeros(size(A,1),size(A,2),size(A,3));
for i=1:size(A,3)
B(:,:,i) =A(indices(:,:,i),:,i);
end
```

In here all values in `A` and `B` are between `0` and `1`. So no point in checking less than 1 and greater than 17. Another thing is that when you delete a row, what are you going to do with the third dimension? If you do the deletion for each third dimension separately `B(:,:,1), B(:,:,2), B(:,:,3), B(:,:,4)`. Each dimension `B(:,:,1), B(:,:,2), B(:,:,3), B(:,:,4)` will have different number of rows. `B` cant have different number of rows like that.

**Updated:** code with sorting and delete rows when **all values** in 2nd column of that row is less than 0.05 or **all values** in 2nd column of that row is greater than 0.15

```
clc;
clear all;

A = rand(10,10,4);

%% sorting
column = 2; % sort base on column
z=A(:,column,:);
[values,indices] = sort(z,1) ;
B=zeros(size(A,1),size(A,2),size(A,3));
for i=1:size(A,3)
B(:,:,i) =A(indices(:,:,i),:,i);
end


%% deleting row
C=B;
column=2; % delete base on column
rowSize=size(C,1);
i=1;
while true
    count=0;
    count1=0;
    for j=1:size(C,3)
        if(C(i,column,j)< 0.05)
            count=count+1;
        end
        if(C(i,column,j)> 0.15)
            count1=count1+1;
        end
    end
    if (count==size(C,3) || count1==size(C,3))
        C(i,:,:)=[];
        rowSize=rowSize-1;
    else
        i=i+1;
    end
    if (i>rowSize)
        break;
    end
end
```

**Updated:** code with sorting and delete rows when **any values** in 2nd column of that row is less than 0.05 or **any values** in 2nd column of that row is greater than 0.15

```
%% deleting row
C=B;
column=2; % delete base on column
rowSize=size(C,1);
i=1;
while true
    flag=0;
    for j=1:size(C,3)
        if(C(i,column,j)< 0.05 || C(i,column,j)> 0.15)
            flag=1;
            break;
        end
    end
    if (flag==1)
        C(i,:,:)=[];
        rowSize=rowSize-1;
    else
        i=i+1;
    end
    if (i>rowSize)
        break;
    end
end
```

Comment: @Rijul.Thank you so much . Actually, in my real data I want to check between 0.05 and 0.15. (1 and 17 is just an example) and delete the rows that not much with that criteria. In addition, In my case after delete extra rows, I will have the same number of rows in all slice. I checked that before.

Comment: ok, since you have written the row deleting code already. Is the sorting, working as expected?

Comment: @ Rijul. Thank you so much. it is working fine.but I can not figure how to delete extra rows that much criteria (any data in column 4 less than 0.05 or greater than 0,15) that row must be delete.

Comment: Cant delete a row alone. if you want to delete 5th row then do `B(5,:,:)=[];`. But you will loose the 5th row with all columns in third dimension also. Try it.

Comment: Will it be ok to fill with zeros instead of deleting the row?

Comment: @ Rijul. Thank you so much. Yes, I want to delete rows that not much that criteria. if the value in 4 column is less than 0.05 or greater than 0.15 then I want to delete all the row in that slice. I used  indices = find(B(:,4,:)> 0.15 & B(:,4,:)<0.05);
B(indices,:) = []; but it is not working

Comment: @ Rijul. Thank you so much. Please, I checked the code and when I run it it looks that there is still data that less than 0.05 in the matrix. I update the question with an image.Also, I have 0.15 values in my data and it should not remove but the code delete. The condition is greater than 0.15 but the code deleted 0.15 values

Comment: @user6052232 It is because currently this code will only remove row if `all the columns are less than 0.05` or `all the columns are greater than 0.15` . I will update that to if `any of the columns are less than 0.05` or `any of the columns are greater than 0.15` then you wont have any data with less than 0.05 or greater than 0.15 in column 2.

Comment: @user6052232 The condition is greater than 0.15. So code wont delete 0.15 values. But will delete 0.1512, 0.1501....... etc.. Anything greater than 0.1500.

Comment: @ Rijul .Thank you so much. Please, it still the same problem. there are numbers less than 0.05 and the code still remove 0.15. I am filtering depending on column 4 so, I changed the column from 2 to 4. but its the same problem.I update the question and this is the link to two slices of results. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7kpduaqb5q9hqg2/AABeUxgTUa7_Nt7hTDQBKDNAa?dl=0

Comment: @user6052232 I have updated the code. I forgot to reset `i` to `1` after sorting. That is why there are numbers less than 0.05. I have corrected it. By adding `i=1;` after `rowSize=size(C,1);`

Comment: @user6052232 For the `0.15`. Code is working properly. You don't have `0.15` in 4th column of matrix `B`. In there what you have is `0.150000006000000`. Which is surely greater than `0.15`. To see this open variable `p1` from workspace. In the variable editor go to row number `4249` 4th column, there you will see `0.1500`. Now double click in the cell showing `0.1500`. Now you will see the truth.

Comment: @ Rijul. Really appreciate. it was a huge effort. it was an excellent answer.